# Loop through json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to loop through json with jQuery ajax. For some reason it's not allowing me to do so. I have received the json from PHP and I JSON.stringify it because it was it was giving me back objects. But, now on the for loop in javascript I need $htmlvalue[i] for I can parse the data.

Thanks for the help.
Hope I described this right.

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
    $nfl = simplexml_load_file('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml');


    $items = array();
    foreach ($nfl->gms->g as $game) {
        foreach($game->attributes() as $a => $b) {
            $items[] = $a;
            $items[] = $b;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

Javascript FILE:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
     url: "nfl.php",
     dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response){
          var $data = response,
              $htmlvalue = '';
          $htmlvalue = JSON.stringify($data.length);
          for(i=0; i < $htmlvalue.length; i++){
             console.log('<h4>' +$htmlvalue[i].eid + "</h4>");
          }
      },
      error: function(){
           console.log("error");
      }
  });
```

Server Response:

```
["eid",{"0":"2014091100"},"gsis",{"0":"56186"},"d",{"0":"Thu"},"t",{"0":"8:25"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"BAL"},"hnn",{"0":"ravens"},"hs",{"0":"26"},"v",{"0":"PIT"},"vnn",{"0":"steelers"},"vs",{"0":"6"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091400"},"gsis",{"0":"56187"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"BUF"},"hnn",{"0":"bills"},"hs",{"0":"29"},"v",{"0":"MIA"},"vnn",{"0":"dolphins"},"vs",{"0":"10"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091401"},"gsis",{"0":"56188"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"CAR"},"hnn",{"0":"panthers"},"hs",{"0":"24"},"v",{"0":"DET"},"vnn",{"0":"lions"},"vs",{"0":"7"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091402"},"gsis",{"0":"56189"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"CIN"},"hnn",{"0":"bengals"},"hs",{"0":"24"},"v",{"0":"ATL"},"vnn",{"0":"falcons"},"vs",{"0":"10"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091403"},"gsis",{"0":"56190"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"CLE"},"hnn",{"0":"browns"},"hs",{"0":"26"},"v",{"0":"NO"},"vnn",{"0":"saints"},"vs",{"0":"24"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091404"},"gsis",{"0":"56191"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"MIN"},"hnn",{"0":"vikings"},"hs",{"0":"7"},"v",{"0":"NE"},"vnn",{"0":"patriots"},"vs",{"0":"30"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091405"},"gsis",{"0":"56192"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"NYG"},"hnn",{"0":"giants"},"hs",{"0":"14"},"v",{"0":"ARI"},"vnn",{"0":"cardinals"},"vs",{"0":"25"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091406"},"gsis",{"0":"56193"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"TEN"},"hnn",{"0":"titans"},"hs",{"0":"10"},"v",{"0":"DAL"},"vnn",{"0":"cowboys"},"vs",{"0":"26"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091407"},"gsis",{"0":"56194"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"1:00"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"WAS"},"hnn",{"0":"redskins"},"hs",{"0":"41"},"v",{"0":"JAC"},"vnn",{"0":"jaguars"},"vs",{"0":"10"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091408"},"gsis",{"0":"56195"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"4:05"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"SD"},"hnn",{"0":"chargers"},"hs",{"0":"30"},"v",{"0":"SEA"},"vnn",{"0":"seahawks"},"vs",{"0":"21"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091409"},"gsis",{"0":"56196"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"4:05"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"TB"},"hnn",{"0":"buccaneers"},"hs",{"0":"17"},"v",{"0":"STL"},"vnn",{"0":"rams"},"vs",{"0":"19"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091410"},"gsis",{"0":"56197"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"4:25"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"DEN"},"hnn",{"0":"broncos"},"hs",{"0":"24"},"v",{"0":"KC"},"vnn",{"0":"chiefs"},"vs",{"0":"17"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091411"},"gsis",{"0":"56198"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"4:25"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"GB"},"hnn",{"0":"packers"},"hs",{"0":"31"},"v",{"0":"NYJ"},"vnn",{"0":"jets"},"vs",{"0":"24"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091412"},"gsis",{"0":"56199"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"4:25"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"OAK"},"hnn",{"0":"raiders"},"hs",{"0":"14"},"v",{"0":"HOU"},"vnn",{"0":"texans"},"vs",{"0":"30"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091413"},"gsis",{"0":"56200"},"d",{"0":"Sun"},"t",{"0":"8:30"},"q",{"0":"F"},"h",{"0":"SF"},"hnn",{"0":"49ers"},"hs",{"0":"20"},"v",{"0":"CHI"},"vnn",{"0":"bears"},"vs",{"0":"28"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"},"eid",{"0":"2014091500"},"gsis",{"0":"56201"},"d",{"0":"Mon"},"t",{"0":"8:30"},"q",{"0":"P"},"h",{"0":"IND"},"hnn",{"0":"colts"},"hs",{"0":"0"},"v",{"0":"PHI"},"vnn",{"0":"eagles"},"vs",{"0":"0"},"rz",{"0":"0"},"ga",{"0":""},"gt",{"0":"REG"}]
```

Comment: You need to parse it, not stringify it. Replace `JSON.stringify` with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: When JSON.parse the data it throws me an error saying: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e

Comment: can you update with an example of what your server is returning?

Comment: Look at the php manual for json_encode(), there is no true expected. http://ch1.php.net/json_encode

Comment: The data you are requesting is xml.

Comment: I took the true out and it still didn't work. I updated it with the server response. The data is XML but I'm converting it to JSON.

Comment: So when you said "*I have received the JSON from PHP*" what you *meant* was "I got some XML from PHP, and then tried to make it into JSON"? Which is an entirely different question.

Comment: Thanks guys/girls for the suggestions/answers. My apologizes; All this is a learning process for me. I'll treat as XML and loop through it. Thanks for the feedback guys/girls.

Comment: The learning never stops so don't worry. This is what these sites are for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change a way of converting your XML data to JSON array. Now it's not in format which you trying to handle by your JavaScript.

```
$items = array();
foreach ($nfl->gms->g as $game) {
    $row = array();
    foreach ($game->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        $row[$a] = (string) $b;
    }
    $items[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

Next step is removing JSON.stringify, because you want to read your response as array, not as string. Using JSON.parse shouldn't be required, because you've passed already information about response format in `$.ajax` call by using `dataType: "JSON"`.

If it still won't work check your response in console and provide results here. It would be also to good idea to use `$.each()` instead of `for()`, beacuse it will be easier to read this array.

Comment: If I may ask a question. What is the (string) doing. Just curious.

Comment: It casts object (in this case SimpleXML Object) to string. It's required to remove any information about object and get clean string.

Answer (score 0):

The json you are trying to parse is not in a format that is easily parsable into meangingful objects. the JSON you have supplied is an array of mixed objects, some strings, e.g. "eid" and some are objects e.g. {"0": "2014091100"}. Your problem is that you are trying to fudge data into a format which is not really suitable. The data is already formatted as it is XML, treat the data as XML and don't try and fudge it into JSON

Comment: That's a good point... The HTML-parsing stuff in jQuery should work for XML too: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ . On the other hand, I personally prefer JSON. I think XML is a bit of a historical legacy: it evolved from HTML, and storing information like this with tags makes sense for webpages (which have text interspersed with markup) but not for data. As far as I'm concerned, if you convert to JSON you're striking a blow against a badly structured data format.